# Why does Django only create one "REFERENCES" clause on a ManyToMany table?

Tags: django, sqlite

With the following Model:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    bar = models.TextField(max_length=40,blank=False,null=False)

class Foo(models.Model):
    foo = models.TextField(max_length=8,blank=False,null=False)
    bars = models.ManyToManyField(Bar)
```

Django 1.6.1 generates:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "example_bar" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "bar" text NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "exmaple_foo_bars" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "foo_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "bar_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "mdtconfig_bar" ("id"),
    UNIQUE ("foo_id", "bar_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "exmaple_foo" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "foo" text NOT NULL
)
;

COMMIT;
```

Why does "foo_id" in "example_foo_bars" not have a "REFERENCES" clause like "bar_id" in the same table?

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Because the exmaple_foo table hasn't been created yet, so it can't add a reference. However it does do that afterwards by doing an ALTER TABLE to add an index, which you can see when you do `./manage.py sqlall`.

However this method of table creation is superseded by the migrations functionality in 1.7.

Comment: I can see (via sqlall) that indexes are created for both example_foo_bars on foo_id and example_foor_bars on bar_id, but there is no alter table adding a reference or index.